# Can we trigger journey once the data is inserted to a data extension in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a requirement to trigger a journey once data is inserted to a data extension. Is this something possible in marketing cloud?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Prasad Ruwanpathirana

Comment: How is the data inserted into the data extension?

Comment: Hi Duc Le,  data inserted via an API call from .net application.

Comment: So instead of adding the data to a DE why don’t you use the entry event API? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_api_entry_source_use_case_1.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Yes, Zuzanna is right. If you are using API for the journey then the best practice is to use the API event entry source

Answer (score 0):

If that data is stored in a sendable DE, you can use it as entry source in your Journey, every time a new record is inserted in the DataExtension the journey will receive a new contact.